# Why: $y | x , \theta \sim N(\theta^T x , \sigma^2)$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Given:

$$\begin{align*}
&\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2),\\\\
&\theta \sim N(0, \eta^2I), \\\\
&\text{And } y^{(i)} = \theta^T x^{(i)} + \epsilon^{(i)} \\\\
\end{align*}$$

Why:
$$y^{(i)} | x^{(i)} , \theta \sim N(\theta^T x^{(i)} , \sigma^2)$$
or
$$y | x , \theta \sim N(\theta^T x , \sigma^2)$$

In other word, why given x,theta, y's normal distribution will have mean:$\theta^T x$ and variance: $\sigma^2$

Can I get more intuitive explaination?

Comment: On the one hand, ChatGPT notoriously gives misleading advice. On the other hand, what exactly is your question? Is it just a confusion about the fact that your $x^{(i)}$ seems to be one-dimensional, but $\theta$ appears to have length greater than one (so ChatGPT wants to transpose it)? Can you clarify which dimension your variables all have?

Comment: Just fixed the equation after "And", I just want to know how can we conclude that relation with those 3 conditions. How N(mean, var) becomes that, I want to get the logical chain step by step, how we from those 3 reach to the y|x ~ N(theta^, sigma^2)

Comment: What have you tried so far to answer your own question?

Comment: @mhdadk, learn more about conditional prob like p(y| x,th) = p(y,x,th) / p(x,th)